# Excel Formula Change- How?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Trying to highlight rows, but want to exclude everything in column F that states Received. Current formula is, =IF(NOT(ISBLANK($F1))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a conditional format you're using, the formula

```
=NOT(OR($F2="Received"))
```

should work. Since you already have a formula you've tried, I assume you're familiar with how to base a conditional format on a formula.

Comment: Why do you include an `OR` in the formula?

Comment: Hmm...good point. =NOT($F2="Received") works just as well.  I included the OR statement out of habit.

Comment: @BillOer incorrect because it than highlights everything...

Comment: When I tested it on my machine, it highlighted all rows except those that contained "Received" in column F. Oh...and "$F2" assumes you have a header row.  If not, change to "$F1".

Comment: @BillOer, tried both $F1 and $F2. Still highlights everything. To start from the beginning because none of these are working, I am looking to highlight everything in red that has been sold, F column, that has a number, but exclude/don't highlight anything that is blank or has the word "Received" in it. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: user449330, you say "...as the word "Received..."  Does this mean that the word "Received" is part of a string within the cells, or does the cell contain only the word "Received"?

Comment: @BillOer, the word "Received" is in a cell without. Do you have an email in which I can send you the Excel sheet, as it may be easier doing is this way as we aren't getting far with results.

Comment: Can you upload your spreadsheet to a file sharing website?  This one is free for less than 5GB:
http://www.filedropper.com/

Comment: Before you upload that file check and see if the cell(s) containing "Received" have any leading or trailing spaces.  That has bitten me in the donkey more than once.

Comment: I don't believe so, here is the link;

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/s_7

Comment: Sorry 'bout that bad site-being-free advice, although 99 cents a month is nearly so.  Anyway if you're trying to clear highlighting for an entire row where "Received" is in column F then try this: highlight your table, and for your Conditional Formatting use the formula "=ISNUMBER(FIND("Received",$F2,1))" and apply no formatting.

Comment: @BillOer, still not working. Here it is on dropbox.

Comment: How is this?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjo29c6e1q6jf87/%23s.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @BillOer, still improper because some of the items are being highlighted in red even though they have not been sold. That is the problem. Is it because numbers are in parentheses?

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused.  In your original post I took you to mean that you wanted rows highlighted except those that contained "Received" in column F.  So let's try this: exactly what do you want highlighted, and what do you not want highlighted?  (I'm sorry if this sounds terse, it's just my writing style.)

Comment: @BillOer, I appreciate the patience, and sorry for the confusion. I want highlighted only the items that have been sold (should have a number in the sold column). Everything else should be blank, or will have the word "Received" in the sold column. I hope it's clear :)

Comment: Something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqk1clk1pf1syjr/%23s.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much, so what was going wrong? Was I confusing people when trying to get the proper formula? How did you come up wit the formula?

Comment: Also if you don't mind deleting the two comments with the links that would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't delete the comments with the links.  I believe only one of the moderators can do that, and I don't believe the links will do any harm.  If you (we) delete the spreadsheets from Dropbox, that should do.  The conditional format formula was pretty straightforward: anything in column F that is a number, i.e. "=ISNUMBER($F2)", which eliminates text.  If you wanted to only highlight positive numbers (i.e. profit as opposed to loss), you could try "=AND(ISNUMBER($F2),$F2>0.01)".  I haven't tested that, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.  Glad I could help.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek

Comment: @Ivo Flipse remove comments showing links to personal information.